# Detecting SmartTV and other TV via User-Agent headers

Tags: user-agent, browser-detection, smart-tv

Any common ways/patterns to detect is device a SmartTV device by `User-Agent` headers?
Probably searching for `TV` or something?

Please advise any other TV related platforms worth detecting?

**UPD**: According to this http://user-agent-string.info/?Fuas=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28SmartHub%3B+SMART-TV%3B+U%3B+Linux%2FSmartTV%29+AppleWebKit%2F531.2%2B+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+WebBrowser%2F1.0+SmartTV+Safari%2F531.2%2B&test=8066&action=analyze `SMART-TV` is it's signature, but...

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: @LiamSorsby, Currently, I'm using this `smart-tv|smarttv|googletv|appletv|hbbtv|pov_tv|netcast.tv` according to http://user-agent-string.info/list-of-ua/device-detail?device=Smart+TV

Comment: in what language are you trying to detect the User-Agent? and what code have you used?

Comment: @LiamSorsby, I'm using `php`, but it absolutely doesn't matter, imho.

Comment: have a look at this git https://gist.github.com/jewelsjacobs/5503790

Comment: @LiamSorsby, thank you! I've already took a look at this. This lib is using `navigator.userAgent.search(/TV/i)`; it seems to me pretty simple and error unprotected.

Answer (score 1):

This PDF describes the "Hybrid Broadcast Broadband TV" Useragent standard for TVs which you will find in the useragent of many (not all) TVs.
This covers a large percentage of the cases.

http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102700_102799/102796/01.01.01_60/ts_102796v010101p.pdf

Relevant quotes:

> 7.3.2.4 HTTP User-Agent header
>
> All outgoing HTTP requests made on behalf of an Hybrid Broadcast Broadband TV application shall include a
> User-Agent header using the syntax described in this clause.
>
> The User-Agent header shall include: HbbTV/1.1.1 (<capabilities>;> [<vendorName>]; [<modelName>]; [<softwareVersion>];> [<hardwareVersion>]; <reserved>) Where:
>
> • The <capabilities> field
> consists of zero or more concatenated Hybrid Broadcast Broadband TV
> option strings as defined in clause 10.2.4.
>
> • The <vendorName>,> <modelName>, <softwareVersion> and <hardwareVersion> fields are the
> same as the one defined in the application/oipfRemoteManagement object
> in the OIPF DAE specification [2] and are optional.
>
> • The <reserved>
> field is reserved for future extensions.
>
> 10.2.4 Hybrid Broadcast Broadband TV option strings
>
> "+DL" Support for file download feature
>
> "+PVR" Support for PVR feature
>
> "+RTSP" Support for RTSP streaming feature

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget Bluray as a possible TV related device.